# How can an annonymus class remove itself from listening to a click event

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a button that I want to **add** a clickListener to it and I want to remove it after the first call.

I saw there is only `setOnClickListener` and not `addOnClickListener` even though there are [articles](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/removeeventlistener-and-anonymous-functions-ab9dbabd3e7b) about that

Do I have to keep a reference to it? It cannot be anonymus?

I saw there is no `removeOnClickListener`

```
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(null);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views only contain reference to one `OnClickListener`.

Calling `View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)` changes that reference - that is previous one is removed and the one provided replaces it as the new listener. If you pass `null` as the argument there will be no listener.

If you want to have multiple click listeners on one View, you have to extend either the button itself or write a custom `OnClickListener` implementation that will aggregate multiple click listeners (ie. list of `OnCLickListeners`).

Comment: from the article it seems possible? or is it not android?
`element.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);`

Comment: @EladBenda that article is tagged as `JavaScript` which has almost nothing in common with Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **counter** variable to achieve your requirement. Refer code below :

```
int counter = 0;    //This is Global variable

closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     ++counter;
     if (counter == 1)
          closeButton.setClickable(false);
     else closeButton.setClickable(true);
  }
});
```